# Get java generic return type of a method which is declared in generic interface

Tags: java, generics, types, return

```
public class Test {

    interface Parent<T> {
        public List<T> get();
    }

    interface Child extends Parent<String> {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Method method = Child.class.getMethod("get");
        Type type = ((ParameterizedType) method.getGenericReturnType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

When I try to get the type argument of a subinterface that uses a specific type, `type` result is `T`, even though in `Child` the generic type is specified as `String`. How can I determine the type for the `get()` method on the subinterface?